# google chrome translate all touch events to click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

Is there a way to tell chrome that all touch events should be handled as click events in Jquery ?

```
global={
    "clickevent":"click tap"
};
```

How could I write the code that it translates every tap into click?

Comment: Can you explain what "weird things" it does, and give us some code for an example of one of your click or touch event handlers?

Comment: I have changed the question entirely thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
global = {
    "clickevent": "click tap"
};

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search("chrome") != -1) {
    global.clickevent = "click";
}
```

If the user agent string of the browser contains the text "chrome" then it will change the global click event name to "click".

You can do it directly within your global object declaration like this...

```
global = {
    "clickevent": navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search("chrome") == -1 ? "click tap" : "click"
};
```

I just find the first option easier to read and easier to extend, but obviously it's your choice.

Incidentally, as a side note, you may want to look at the "touchstart" event as that's a lot more usable with mobile devices, as it ignores the pause that is required to differentiate between a click and a double click, therefore making it a *LOT* faster...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchstart